# Java JNI: How to create an array of byte arrays in native code?

Tags: java

I'm looking to create an array of byte arrays in native code. I plan to use NewObjectArray() for the outer array, since Java arrays are objects. What should I specify as the class identifier for a Java byte array?

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NewByteArray](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jnistring.html) allocates a jbyteArray (which corresponds to byte[]).  Each of the primitive types has its own array handling functions in JNI.

Comment: This is not what he asked. He needs an array of byte arrays. Not just a single byte array. You should call `NewObjectArray()`, telling the array size and the class type - and the question is what class type should be specified for `byte[]`, since the whole array is `byte[][]`